# Get OpenGL max texture size

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing an Android app that's going to work with bitmaps extensively and I'm looking for a reliable way to get the maximum texture size for OpenGL on different devices. 
I know the minimum size = 2048x2048, but that's not good enough since there are already tablets out there with much higher resolutions (2560x1600 for example)
So is there a reliable way to get this information?
 
So far I've tried:

- Canvas.getMaximumBitmapWidth() (Returns 32766, instead of 2048)
- GLES10.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE ...) (Returns 0)

I'm working with minimum-sdk = 15 (ICS) and I'm testing it on a Asus Transformer TF700t Infinity

Does anyone know another way to get it?
Or will I have to compile a list of known GPUs with their max canvas size?

Comment: Do you have a valid gl context when you call that `glGetIntegerv()`?

Answer (score 6):

try using this code

```java
int[] maxTextureSize = new int[1];
GLES10.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);
```

`maxTextureSize` stores the size limit for decoded image such as 4096x4096, 8192x8192 . Remember to run this piece of code in the **MainThread** or you will get Zero.

Comment: Even if you are in MainThread, you could come up with `E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)`, and get result 0.

Comment: The "MainThread" might happen to be the OpenGL thread, but it doesn't have to be. Basically call this in the same thread you would use to allocated textures and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the maximum height allowed.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight() / 8
```

Comment: But only if you are in a View that is being drawn. Otherwise you'll get a constant value.

Comment: Why you have to divide by 8? (Works, but I am curious)

Comment: It's not true. `getMaximumBitmap(Height|Width)()` on a software rendered canvas returns a [constant value](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.0.0_r21/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java#293), while  hardware accelerated canvas returns [real](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/UFjDiBUfY78/v0XWoBlkvR8J) `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`. I have tested it on several devices. The division by 8 is just a mere coincidence.