# Android. W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

When I call `Canvas.drawBitmap()` for a `Bitmap` with more than 4096px on one side - I get nothing. No errors and no bitmap drawn. There appears only this message in LogCat:

> W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2880x4920, max=4096x4096)

This leads to these questions:

1. What does the limit of 4096x4096 depend on? The Android version? The Kernel drivers? Or the Hardware?
2. How can I check this limit at runtime for the current device?
3. How can I catch the error *"W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large ..."*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on both hardware and software.  You can query at runtime with a valid OpenGL context (see: [Get OpenGL max texture size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981125/get-opengl-max-texture-size))

```
int[] maxTextureSize = new int[1];
GLES10.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);
```

Note that the supported size might be smaller, depending on the format of the texture.  For example, your hardware could also have a maximum texture size, in bytes, in addition to a maximum size in pixels.  To check what texture size is supported, create a proxy texture (`GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D` target, instead of `GL_TEXTURE_2D`) with the size and format you want, and then query the texture size (width or height) with `glGetTexLevelParameteriv()`.  If your texture is too big, the size will be set to 0.

Comment: There are no proxy textures in OpenGL ES.

Comment: Thank you. `glGetIntegerv` working.
But only in the `onDraw` event..  If I make call in `onSizeChanged` and `onAttachedToWindow` it returns 0. It need to create custom GL context..

Comment: @GennadyZavodovskiy: Yes, you need a valid OpenGL context.